# Shortcut key to next breakpoint in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, breakpoints

I'm using Visual Studio and would like to use the keyboard to go to the previous/next breakpoint. I had a look at Options|Environment|Keyboard but found no such command.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: For future visitors, you can vote on this feature request on [Visual Studio User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/32759428-add-previous-breakpoint-next-breakpoint-function).

Answer (score 30):

For people wanting to see each breakpoint, that ended up here. (Like me)

Try **Debug** -> **Windows** -> **Breakpoints**.

[image]

Comment: Yep, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 24):

You can jump to breakpoints during debugging of application. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239052(v=vs.60).aspx) is a list of shortcut keys that might help you.

- Create or remove breakpoint on the current line: <kbd>F9</kbd>
- Execute code one statement at a time, following execution into function calls (Step Into): <kbd>F11</kbd>
- Execute the next line of code but not follow execution through any function calls (Step Over): <kbd>F10</kbd>
- Execute the remaining lines of a function in which the current execution point lies (Step Out): <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
- Restart a debugging session : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Resume execution of your code from the current statement to the selected statement (Run to Cursor): <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
- Run the application (or jump to next breakpoint): <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the shortcut key to jump to next or previous breakpoint in your link. Can you tell me which one it is?

Comment: You can press F5 while debugging to jump to next breakpoint and F10 to jump line by line. It works in C# so hopefully should do the same in C++ also.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to go to next breakpoint in the breakpoint list, not during debugging. Similarly by pressing F2 you can quickly loop through all bookmarks.

Comment: Breakpoints are usually meant to be traversed while debugging since then you can check out the values that current code retrieves etc. for rest you can traverse easily using bookmarks.

Comment: I think the original poster wants to use breakpoints as an alternative / supplement to bookmarks. That way, after debugging, you can easily find that bit of code you were just looking at to make changes.

Answer (score 3):

Use **'Run To Cursor'** (CTRL+F10). The debugger will execute your application up to where your cursor is and break. For more details visit: [How to skip over code in the Visual Studio Debugger](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/07/30/debugging-101-how-to-skip-over-code-in-the-visual-studio-debugger/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just want to navigate and not use debugger, I use an extension called Bookmarks by Alessandro Fragnani.  It's super useful when you have to navigate forward and backwards through long lines of code on a page and even faster if you setup shortcut keys.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is how to Configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyzWp.png)

I've configured mine shortcut key Manually

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add some details to enrich your answere and avoid semding simple image as the answere.